# What parts of speech are in the sentence, “He went to the moon”?

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech

What  parts of speech are in this sentence:

> He went to the moon.

I’m confused about part of speech to assign to   *“to the moon”*.

Comment: Well, _to_ is a preposition, so...

Comment: _Parts of speech_ are traditionally words, not phrases, so in a traditional analysis _to the moon_ is not a part of speech. In some more modern analyses, it is a Prepositional Phrase (PP)

Comment: The sentence has the same structure as He went to London. He went + where-to. The where-to indication consists of the preposition to and the noun group the moon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> He went to the moon.

In terms of the different parts of the sentence, there are the *functions* that different words and phrases are carrying out, functions such as *Subject*. There is also a question of what types of words and phrases are doing these jobs, for example Nouns and Verbs.

In terms of the jobs or functions that the words are doing. The structure of the sentence is as follows:

- Subject ***He***, Predicator ***went***, [Locative] Complement ***to the moon***.

The parts of speech and types of phrase here are as follows:

- ***He*** Pronoun, ***went*** Verb, ***to the moon*** Preposition Phrase.

The verb *GO* here selects a Preposition Phrase headed by the Preposition ***to*** (the verb *GO* and the preposition ***to*** have special relationship). The complement of ***to*** is the Noun Phrase ***the moon***.

[Some people will label *to the moon* here an Adverb or Adverbial clause. It is not. Adverbs cannot usually function as the complements of Verbs].

Comment: Yes, but also "he" and "the moon" are noun phrases; "went to the moon" is a verb phrase; "to" is a preposition; "moon" is a noun; "the" is a determiner.

Comment: @GregLee Yes, quite so. Missed out the predicate too!

Comment: I think the prepositional phrase can be considered adverbial, since the direct object of 'go' is null (self), and there is really only two ways to store predicate info: 1) as a relation under the subject (a verb or adverbial), and 2) as a referent of a relation (object).

Answer (score 0):

> He went to the moon.

- *he* = subject
- *went* = verb
- *to* = preposition
- *the moon* = object

Comment: Note that 'to' is a highly "overloaded" word.  In this case it would be less ambiguous by using the word 'unto'.

Answer (score 0):

- He = pronoun
- went = verb
- to = preposition
- the = article
- moon = noun